# USB drive's name/label was permanently changed while it's actually empty label

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

Yes, my USB drive's (specifically in **E** letter) name/label was permanently changed to something else (named '**sad**') when it is empty when I open up the properties.
**If I key in some name in properties or simply rename it, it shows the name I've typed, however when I cleared it, it shows something else instead of 'USB drive'**.
This is only happened when it is specifically drive in letter E only. I've used a third-party software to change the letter of the **exact same USB device on the exact same USB port** to letter F and it shows normal 'USB drive'. Therefore, I believe this should not be some problem deal with my USB device but Windows system error in somewhere.

Extra info here:

1. **I did restart my PC but the problem persisted.**
2. **Why this problem occurred was because of once upon a time in *My Computer* I've saw a drive E device but it is actually nothing there. It cannot be double clicked so I simply rename 'sad' on the drive. And I believe it must be something wrong with systems, so I restart my PC, that drive E is gone but the name 'sad' is permanently stick on letter E now.**
End of story. Thanks for reading my questions. Please help me to change the name although it doesn't caused a big deal. Thanks.
Here are some screenshot
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA6oW.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P80x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Empty the drive, then whilst plugged in, Right Click on the drive and Format, during the formatting process you are free to name the drive whatever you would like.

Sorry for the simple answer to this question but don't believe a more difficult answer would be required.

You could do the following if you are having issues formatting,

Open Command Prompt as administrator,

type **Diskpart**

type **list disk**

type **select disk x** where x is the disk number for your usb drive.

type **clean**

type **create partition primary**

unplug your usb pen drive then plug it back in, windows should then ask if you want to format this drive, choose yes.

once formatted the pen drive should only display the name "Removable Disk"

Comment: not sure how you rename it while formatting but I failed to do that anyway no matter using Quick Format or not. First it asking me for providing Admin privilege, then access denied.

Comment: @ElliotChingLee When you rightclick on the device and choose format, you can put a name in "Volume label" and that will be the name of your USB device when plugged into any PC.

Comment: @ElliotChingLee updated my answer to use diskpart to clean your pendrive before formatting.

Comment: i solved it. By using empty USB card reader (no card inserted), and rename it.

Comment: Np. Create an answer yourself so others could try your idea if they have a similar problem